Problema 'Nonetype' has no attribute 'group' para Pandas_DataReader
Estoy llevando un curso de python y en un ejercicio tengo un error en la línea de
DataReader(AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group') 

y no comprendo qué está mal, agradecería su ayuda:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

PG = wb.DataReader("PG", data_source="yahoo", start="1995-1-1")
print(PG)


No uso esta librería pero pude reproducir el problema.
El error se produce en esta línea de pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py
:
resp = self._get_response(url, params=params, headers=self.headers)
ptrn = r"root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);"
try:
    j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1)) # <<<<<<<<<<

y se debe a que al parsear la respuesta de Yahoo Finance usando la la expresión regular con re.search() no se encuentra ninguna coincidencia. Cuando re.search no encuentra una coincidencia retorna None en vez de una instancia re.Match, y None lógicamente no tiene un método group() como lo tiene re.Match:
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"(bor)", "foobar").group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

En contraposición a cuando si se encuentra una coincidencia:
>>> re.search(r"(bar)", "foobar").group(1)
'bar'

Indagando en el repositorio de GitHub no aparecen issues con este error en concreto pero si hay varias relacionadas con Yahoo Finance que llevan sin resolverse ya bastante tiempo pero siguen activas. Al parecer Yahoo cambió la API y la estructura de las respuestas y pandas_datareader no parece funcionar a día de hoy correctamente con esta fuente de datos.
Podrías intentar dos cosas, seguir usando pandas_datareader y cambiar la fuente de los datos, por ejemplo usando
Stooq:
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr


PG = pdr.DataReader('PG', data_source='stooq', start="1995-1-1")

o usar yfinance, instalándolo previamente:
python -m pip install yfinance

y luego simplemente:
import yfinance as yf


PG = yf.download('PG', "1995-1-1")

Ten en cuenta que el DataFrame generado por yfinace difiere en algunos aspectos con el de pandas_datareader, por ejemplo, tiene una columna extra (Adj Close) y los datos están ordenados de más antiguo a más reciente.

Edición
En algunas issues de las mencionadas se proponía como solución temporal (ver comentario en GitHub y respuesta original en StackOverflow) hacer esto:
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import yfinance as yf


yf.pdr_override()
PG = pdr.DataReader('PG', start="1995-1-1")

Aunque funciona, esto actualmente genera el siguiente warning por parte de yfinance:
yfinance: pandas_datareader support is deprecated & semi-broken so will be removed in a future verison. Just use yfinance.

El "Just use yfinance" es simplemente mi segunda opción planteada más arriba.

Hola, muchas gracias!!!! Me funcionó instalar el módulo yfinance
